# Flex css embedding google font

Tags: css, apache-flex, fonts, flash-builder, flex4.6

Are you able to embed a google font in css in flex?

Example Css:

```
@font-face { 
    src: url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans"); 
    fontFamily: "Open Sans"; 
    fontStyle: normal; 
    fontWeight: normal;
}

s|Application{
    fontFamily: "Open Sans";
}
```

Because that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO you are right that will NOT work AS IS!
https://typekit.com/fonts/open-sans try this and get the font file as well there are many more if you research this font! regards aktell